# Using Java Comparator for sorting using multiple fields based on condition

Tags: java, sorting, collections, filter, comparator

I have a question on effective use of Java Comparator.

```
class MyClass {
    //Active State: OPEN, PENDING, RUNNING
    private String state;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
}
```

Here the possible values of `state` field are OPEN, PENDING, RUNNING, CLOSED, CANCELLED etc., out of which OPEN, PENDING and RUNNING are the **Active state**. Now I want to write comparator which sorts the `List<MyClass>`, so that the active ones comes first and are sorted by `startDate` followed by non-active ones which are sorted based on `endDate`.

```
static final Set<String> ACTIVE;// this set contains OPEN, PENDING, RUNNING

List<MyClass> myList;//This is my list
...
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<MyClass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
        int c;
        boolean isO2 = ACTIVE.contains(o2.getState());
        boolean isO1 = ACTIVE.contains(o1.getState());
        if (isO2 && isO1) {
            c = DateTimeComparator.getInstance().compare(o2.getStartDate(), o1.getStartDate());
        } else if (isO2) {
            c = 1;
        } else if (isO1) {
            c = -1;
        } else {
            c = DateTimeComparator.getInstance().compare(o2.getEndDate(), o1.getEndDate());
        }
        return c;
    }
});
```

My question is whether my above implementation of having single comparator good? or are there better ways to do it? 
Most likely I have to stick with Java 7 but solutions with Java 8 are welcome too.

Comment: Question: why is your active state a String? Wouldn't an enum be more appropriate here?

Comment: BTW: I don't have issue with your implementation but you'd best wait for someone more expert in this to fully weigh in.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Unfortunately I can not make any change in `MyClass` as we don't own it, just simply using it. May be I need to ask the corresponding team to make it enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8, I think it would be a bit cleaner to use [Comparator::comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-). For example:

```
Comparator<MyClass> comparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing((MyClass myClass) -> !isActive(myClass))
    .thenComparing((MyClass myClass) -> isActive(myClass) ? myClass.startDate : myClass.endDate, Comparator.nullsFirst(DateTimeComparator.getInstance())));

private static boolean isActive(MyClass myClass)
{
    switch (myClass.state)
    {
    case "OPEN":
    case "PENDING":
    case "RUNNING":
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

In Java 7, assuming you have Guava on the classpath, you could use [Ordering](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/OrderingExplained). For example:

```
Comparator<MyClass> comparator = Ordering.natural().reverse().onResultOf(new Function<MyClass, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(MyClass myClass) {
            return isActive(myClass);
        }
    })
    .compound(Ordering.from(DateTimeComparator.getInstance()).nullsFirst().onResultOf(new Function<MyClass, Date>() {
        @Override
        public Date apply(MyClass myClass) {
            return isActive(myClass) ? myClass.startDate : myClass.endDate;
        }
    }))
    .nullsFirst();
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent of this in Java 7? This is good though. +1

Comment: How will the dates the compared here? In my solution I am using DateTimeComparator. What will he be used here if the dates are joda time?

Comment: You can pass your DateTimeComparator as the second parameter to thenComparing. See the updated code.

Comment: I don't think there's a particularly elegant solution in Java 7 without the use of Guava or another library.

Comment: I added an example in Java 7, though unfortunately it requires Guava.

Comment: Just one more question, how do we handle `null` values here?

Comment: Java 8 has Comparator::nullsFirst and Guava has Ordering::nullsFirst. Of course you could swap for nullsLast in either case. I updated the examples above.